# change url on git receiving error of wrong password

Tags: node.js, express, github, gitlab

i was using github but now i am using gitlab and receiving error.
my vscode was login from my github account now i am trying to login through gitlab account and in my vscode the user id and password is saved to github userid and password.

the error is as follows:

when typing the command "node index.js"

```
Example app listening at http://:::8089
Error ReplyError: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair
/home/leonids/Documents/platform/trayistats.gitlab.api/platformapi.trayistats.com/middlewares/redisClient.js:37
                throw err;
                ^

ReplyError: WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair
    at parseError (/home/leonids/Documents/platform/trayistats.gitlab.api/platformapi.trayistats.com/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/home/leonids/Documents/platform/trayistats.gitlab.api/platformapi.trayistats.com/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) {
  command: 'AUTH',
  args: [ 'qUZzuDDikoNMUb0OXSxztVuLY518FJPDmAzCaGOy8ao=' ],
  code: 'WRONGPASS'
}
```

can anyone please  help me  to solve this error

I tryed to git clone the project from git lab account
and still getting the  same error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as a password, not your actual GitHub account password.

Your token should [start with `ghp_...`](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/#identifiable-prefixes).

Comment: using git token as a password

Comment: @akshatchawla Does your token start with `ghp_...`?

Comment: yes my token is starting with  ghp_IG...

Comment: @akshatchawla "now i am trying to login through gitlab account"... so that password would not work for GitLab, right?

Comment: The both the platforms are having different access tokens and for using gitlab it is saying the popping a wrong password error

Comment: @akshatchawla Do you pass as argument bith the GitLab account name and the password/GitLab token? From your code, I only see a token.

Comment: yes i have checked and i am passing same id and password of gitlab account

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250601/discussion-between-vonc-and-akshat-chawla).